# How to identify a roadway item on a map?

Tags: here-api

I am using the Traffic API to collect speed of streets. As a response, I got a list of roadways (RW), and each one has a list of flow items (FI). But reading the description (DE) of the roadways, I noticed that for the same road there are a bunch of roadway items. And each FI of a RW has a description with a name of another road (not necessarily connected to the current RW).

**Example:**

`<RW LI="B14+05453" DE="Av Cristiano Machado" PBT="2016-04-20T22:08:55Z" mid="8a961c28-7d3c-481f-a6c4-bd1ca1b699f0|">
    <FIS>
        <FI>
            <TMC PC="5454" DE="R Nossa Senhora De Fátima" QD="-" LE="0.04553"/>
            <CF CN="0.78" FF="39.0" JF="0.0" SP="44.45" SU="44.45" TY="TR"/>
        </FI>
        <FI>
            <TMC PC="5455" DE="Av Presidente Antônio Carlos" QD="-" LE="0.1193"/>
            <CF CN="0.76" FF="39.0" JF="0.0" SP="42.03" SU="42.03" TY="TR"/>
        </FI>
        ...
    </FIS>
<\RW>`

This is a small portion of a response. There is a RW called "Av Cristiano Machado" and two FI listed. The second FI, "Av Presidente Antônio Carlos" is anoter road, but it doens't intersect with "Av Cristiano Machado" in the reality.

**My question is:**

**Based on the identifier of the RW (I think it's LI), how to indentify on a map which part of the road it represents? Is it possible to convert a RW item into a polyline or maybe get its coordinates?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, after a thorough reading I learned about [responseattributes](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/traffic/topics_v6.1/resource-parameters-flow.html). Adding **"&responseattributes=sh"** to the request, it returns the shape of each flow item, which is a group of georeferenced points. You can plot and connect them through a line and I assume this is the section of the road it represents.

This figure is a result I obtained using Google MyMaps, LI="B14+05656" and LI="B14-05656". On the left hand (green) the coordinates seem really precise, not so much on the right hand of the image (red). The blue line is a valid driving route.

[image: map with the shape of a road section]

Comment: In general, If a HERE API is used to retrieve a shape then , HERE map tiles should also be rendered them as well as mentioned in Terms and Condition https://developer.here.com/terms-and-conditions  (You are not allowed to display or visualize Results on any third party content (such as map, views from streets, or satellite imagery).)